# Kinesis Firehose to S3 object name with extension

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis

I am streaming my JSON data into a Kinesis Firehose and dropping them into S3 with 
 this custom prefix: `short_date=!{timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd}/`. I know Firehose won't recognize this as JSON data by itself and I don't know how to add an extension for the S3 file object. Firehose drops data as a plain text file (without any extensions). How to add .json extension to my data?

Answer (score 3):

You can't tell firehose to add the .json extension, however, you could setup an s3 event notification that gets fired on every S3 'put' and write a small lambda function that renames it for you if that is required.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue lately, Ended up writing a small lambda function which triggers when new data stream to s3 and adds the extension, I used this tutorial :

https://medium.com/lambdatv/integrating-s3-with-lambda-plus-some-use-cases-e82d3a02defc